# IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation does not implement the interface hbase.client.Connection

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I get the below exception:

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
    at com.itworx.bigdata.mediasensor.cascade.dao.impl.ImpalaAuthorDao.queryUserFollowers(ImpalaAuthorDao.java:107)
    at com.itworx.bigdata.mediasensor.cascade.service.impl.AuthorServiceImpl.getNodesByHashtag(AuthorServiceImpl.java:46)
    at com.itworx.bigdata.mediasensor.cascade.service.test.AuthorServiceTest.testJob(AuthorServiceTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringTestMethod.invoke(SpringTestMethod.java:198)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTestMethod(SpringMethodRoadie.java:274)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$2.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:207)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:234)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:204)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:146)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation does not implement the requested interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegistryFactory.getRegistry(RegistryFactory.java:35)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.setupRegistry(ConnectionManager.java:882)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:647)
    ... 33 more
```

as I try to run test case on my machine that requires connection to server to connect to hbase. my code goes like this:

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set(HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM, HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_VAL);
        Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
        Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("schemaname.tablename"));
        FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE);
        Scan s = new Scan();

        for(String user:users){
            PrefixFilter filter=new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes(user));
            filterList.addFilter(filter);
        }
        s.setFilter(filterList);
        ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(s);
        for (Result r = scanner.next(); r != null; r = scanner.next()) {
            for (KeyValue kv : r.raw()) {
                System.out.println(kv.getValue()+" "+kv.getKey());
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
```

I don't understand why this exception is caused, can anyone help me to figure out the problem

**Update**
here are the dependencies used:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>

                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>0.90.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-examples</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-prefix-tree</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.htrace</groupId>
            <artifactId>htrace-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-incubating</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: my first guess would be that you are not using the right jar with your hbase. Can you show us your dependencies?

Comment: @Whitefret updated

Comment: I think you have the wrong jar for hbase. you don't need the jar from version 0.93 because it was separated in multiple jars (client, server, annotation and maybe other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to one of below reasons.

1. Multiple versions of same jar is present in classpath. Check container logs. It would list classpath. This classpath shows up the directories from where jars would be loaded at run time. Keenly observe each and every directory. At least one of the directory should have multiple versions of hbase jars. Keep the one specific to your hadoop provider(HDP, CDH, Mapr etc..). Delete rest all jars.
2. Multiple versions of hbase jars listed in your dependencies.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
       <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
       <version>0.90.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
       <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

**hbase 0.90.3** does not has **ConnectionFactory**, **Connection**, **Table** classes and interfaces. Please check it at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhbase0903jar.htm. Where as **hbase-client 1.0.0-cdh5.4.2** has all of these. I manually downloaded the jar from https://javalibs.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client and verified using java decompiler.

It would not be an issue at compile time. But at run time, after you submit yarn job, it loads hbase 0.90.3 jar and would not be able to find necessary classes and interfaces. Please remove this entry from dependencies. This should fix the issue.